# Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together Google Analytics REST API with E-Commerce Metrics and Dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Here is the Request Body Object. I have read the Dimensions and Metrics API chart. But I'm getting the error.

It looks like a valid combination of Metrics and Dimension.

```
  { reportRequests: [
                              {
                                viewId: 'XXXXX',
                                dateRanges: [

                                  {
                                    startDate: '2016-11-01',
                                    endDate: '2016-12-31'
                                  }
                                ],
                                metrics: [

                                  {
                                    expression: 'ga:transactionRevenue'
                                  }

                                ],
                                dimensions: [
                                 {
                                     name: 'ga:productCategory'
                                 }
                                ],
                                pageSize: 10

                              }
                            ]}
```

I need to get the Total Revenue based on Product Category. I'm able to get Product wise Revenue using `ga:localItemRevenue` Metric. I tried multiple combinations but failed to figure out how to get the Total Revenue based on Product Category. Could someone help me out.

Comment: What’s the output you’re getting with that?

Answer (score 1):

Product Category dimension is a Product-scope field while Transaction is a hit. A single transaction could have multiple products from different categories and therefore summarising transaction revenue per product category will not accurate.
You can try these dimensions;

- Avg. Price (ga:revenuePerItem)
- Product Revenue (ga:itemRevenue)
- Product Revenue per Purchase (ga:productRevenuePerPurchase)